# Surface intensity for a moving light source

Tags: matlab, light

I’m trying to write a simulation that will move a light source over the surface of an object, on each step measure the intensity of reflected light back to the light source.

Then plot the intensity from each point of the surface. With each step adding to the first plot.  Thus building up a picture of the surface topography.

It is a bit messy if you can suggest a way to tidy up.

```
x = -10:0.25:10;
y = -10:0.25:10;
xlength=length(x);
ylength=length(y);
ymin=min(y);
ymax=max(y);
xmin=min(x);
xmax=max(x);
D=zeros(xlength);


[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = 10-(X.^2)-(Y.^2)+5*sin(X);
rnd=rand(xlength);

c=randi(xlength);
d=randi(xlength); 
s=1;
t=0;


for i=1:ylength
    t=t+1;
    for j=1:xlength
        if s==c
            if t==d 
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+1
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+2
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+3
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+4
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+5
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            else
                D(s,t)=0;
            end
        elseif s==c+1
            if t==d
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+1
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+2
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+3
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+4
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+5
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            else
                D(s,t)=0;
            end
        elseif s==c+2
            if t==d
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+1
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+2
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+3
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+4
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+5
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            else
                D(s,t)=0;
            end
        elseif s==c+3
            if t==d
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+1
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+2
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+3
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+4
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+5
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            else
                D(s,t)=0;
            end
        elseif s==(c+4)
            if t==d
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+1
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+2
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+3
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+4
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
            elseif t==d+5
                D(s,t)=z(s,t);
             else
                D(s,t)=0;
            end
        else
            D(s,t)=0;
        end
        s=s+1;
    end
    s=1;
end       

z1=z -(D/20);
z2=z1-z;

s=0;

figure
surf(X,Y,z)
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])

xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
    for i=-10:2.5:10
        hold on

        light('position',[i,0,50])
        surf(X,Y,z,'EdgeColor', 'none')
        axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])

        drawnow

        pause (1)
        delete(findall(gcf,'Type','light'))

        hold off
    end
```

This is as far as I have got .

Comment: There is not enough information to answer (and what is the exact question by the way?). You have to give a minimal sample for `X`, `Y` and `z` so one can run your code. You also have to describe more what is not working as expected in your code and what should be the desired output.

Comment: Now the code runs, thanks. Still the question is unclear. Is there something wrong with the output ? Or do you just want to "tidy up" ? If the later you can start by removing all the top double `for` loop where you define `D, s, z1, z2, etc...` because you never use them in the display later on.

Comment: This might be more appropriate on [codereview.se]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A code that does exactly what yours does: (thanks @Hoki for the help in simplifying the code even more)

```
clear;clc
x = -10:0.25:10;
y = -10:0.25:10;
xlength=length(x);
ylength=length(y);
ymin=min(y);
ymax=max(y);
xmin=min(x);
xmax=max(x);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = 10-(X.^2)-(Y.^2)+5*sin(X);

%% plot!

figure
surf(X,Y,z,'EdgeColor', 'none','lineStyle','none') % taken out the linestyle because it looks cooler
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])

xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
% Added repetitions and decreased step size, plus making it go forward and backward.
repetitions=4;
for jj=1:repetitions

   hl = light('position',[-10,0,50]) ;     %// create the light source
   for i=-10:2.5:10
       set(hl,'position',[i,0,50]) ;       %// set the new light position
       drawnow                             %// flush graphic pipeline
       pause (0.1)                         %// let human user see something
   end
   delete(hl)   %// delete the light source
end
```

This gives the following gif:

http://i.imgur.com/42ffYll.gifv

About the rest part of the code....

Remember that

```
if t==d
   D(s,t)=z(s,t);
elseif t==d+1
   D(s,t)=z(s,t);
elseif t==d+2
   D(s,t)=z(s,t);
elseif t==d+3
   D(s,t)=z(s,t);
elseif t==d+4
   D(s,t)=z(s,t);
elseif t==d+5
   D(s,t)=z(s,t);
else
   D(s,t)=0;
end
```

is literally the same as:

```
if (t>=d && t<=d+5)
   D(s,t)=z(s,t);
else
    D(s,t)=0;
end
```

This should help you reduce the code. 
There is also vectorization.

you can do

```
D(s,(t>=d && t<=d+5))=z(s,(t>=d && t<=d+5)));
```

for all values of `s`... etc etc. Hope this gets you going ;)

Comment: Thank you I have managed to massively reduce the size of the code